# how can i add column names at 1st row of list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a basic linq that gets 10 rows from database; get 2 columns (First_Name & Last_Name) from database. - this works ok

**Question** - how can i add column names at 1st row of list?

```
var query = _context1.dbset
                     .Select(x =>
                           new
                           {
                               First_Name = x.First_Name,
                               Last_Name = x.Last_Name
                           }).Take(10).ToList();
```

**What I tried.** Below works good but I have to manually type all column names and also when adding data in for loop
`

```
            List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
            data .Add(new object[] { "First_Name", "Last_Name" });
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
               Data.Add(new object[] { item.First_Name, item.Last_Name });
            }
```

Comment: Sounds a little bit like xy-problem to me. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: a table api requires to have columns names in first row of list. For example `List<object> data = new List<object>();` this works good with an api, since it has column names in 1st row.

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection:

```
var query = _context1.dbset
                 .Select(x =>
                       new
                       {
                           First_Name = x.First_Name,
                           Last_Name = x.Last_Name
                       }).Take(10).ToList();

var columnNames = query[0].GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();

var result = new List<object> { columnNames };
result.AddRange(query);
```

Comment: that would mix the data (possible different order in colum names and the data array)

Comment: Cleptus, agree, it's just to indicate how extract the column name, after he may perform a sort in columns and data rows in order to align.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code

```
var query = _context1.dbset...

var properties = JArray.FromObject(query).Select(j => ((JObject)j).Properties());

List<List<object>> data = new List<List<object>> { properties.Select(ja => ja.Select(p => (object)p.Name).ToList()).First() };

data.AddRange(properties.Select(ja => ja.Select(p => p.Value.ToObject<object>()).ToList()).ToList());
```